# Is there a way to find the comments that I have made on SO?

Tags: support, comments, search

I was requested to reply from within a comment sequence, and now that I have the reply, I can't remember which question/answer the comment was under.

Is there any hope for finding it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it was Recent

Account (Your Name on the top bar) > Activity

This will list the recent things you did, and if you commented on the same answer, it will be there.

You can also click on the Envelope > Responses.

That will be a list of comments to your answers that have recently happened.

Comment: I found it on the second page of the listing of my Answers, the title of the question finally range the appropriate bell Thx.

Answer (score 1):

If your comment is older than one month and it has not been deleted, you can look it up in [Data Explorer](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/94/my-comments).

Answer (score 0):

Or, through [api](http://stackapps.com),

> http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/users/8362/comments?type=jsontext